# Changing default Directory of Jupyter Notebook not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I had anaconda installed (along with jupyter notebook) previously before a system crash necessitated reinstalling Windows OS.

Previously, I was easily able to change my default Jupyter Notebook directly (but it was on the same drive as where Anaconda / Jupyter was installed).

However, now I am unable to do so.

I thought it might be because now I have separated my drives for Data (D Drive) and Applications (C Drive). I wish to open Jupyter in the default D drive while anaconda and jupyter are in C drive. I tried testing with a folder in the C Drive (where jupyter is installed). But THAT didn't work either.

I tried various things: single forward slashes, double forward slashes, single backward slashes, double backward slashes, using r before the quotes (raw string), ensuring no spaces in the folder names - everything I could think of. I have repeatedly deleted and recreated the config.py file as well. Images follow:

Update - Attached only the config file setting that I have changed.

I wished to show all the steps - Trying to change default to C Drive, folder structure, where I expected to open and where it actually opens. Trying the same thing for D Drive, where I expected to open (and it opens in the default folder only where jupyter is installed). However, unable to load more than one pic(newest pic overwrites the older one) and imgur is not allowing me to register from India.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks[image]